# Accessing the class object from the Dependancy Proprty Changed Callback

Tags: wpf, vb.net, xaml, dependency-properties

I am having trouble accessing a lable in my custom WPF control. I have implemented the PropertyChangedCallback but from there I can't get access to the class.
The class is a simple control with a lable (Name="lblDataName") that I want to change the text to match the DataName property.
Here is the code behind:

```
Public Class DataNameControl

Public Property DataName As String
    Get
        Return GetValue(DataNameProperty)
    End Get

    Set(ByVal value As String)
        SetValue(DataNameProperty, value)
    End Set
End Property

Public Shared ReadOnly DataNameProperty As DependencyProperty = _
                       DependencyProperty.Register("DataName", _
                       GetType(String), GetType(GraphData), _
                       New PropertyMetadata("KPI", AddressOf OnDataNameChanged))

Public Shared Function OnDataNameChanged(ByVal d As DependencyObject, ByVal e As DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs) As String
    Dim dnc As DataNameControl = CType(d, DataNameControl)
    dnc.lblDataName.Text = e.NewValue.ToString
    '' I want to access the lable on my class right here.
    Return e.NewValue.ToString
End Function
End class
```

I would hope that setting the property in XAML would update the label accordingly, but nada!

```
 <Controls:DataNameControl DataName="BCWP" Margin="0"/>
```

There are tons of answer on how to change the property itself, but none seem to answer this specifically, and if been tinkering for 20 hours on this one issue.  Time ask for help!

Comment: The third parameter to Register is wrong. It must be `GetType(DataNameControl)` instead of `GetType(GraphData)`. The cast `CType(d, DataNameControl)` should work. However, a PropertyChangedCallback does not return a value, so (as far as I understand VB) it should be a Sub, not a Function. You should also show where `lblDataName` is declared and how it is displayed in DataNameControl.

Comment: BRILLIANT!!!!!  That was it.  I had moved this section of the class over from another class and missed changing the Class Name in the registration!  Thanks TONS @Clemens

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The third parameter of the Register method is wrong. It must be `GetType(DataNameControl)` instead of `GetType(GraphData)`:

```
Public Shared ReadOnly DataNameProperty As DependencyProperty = _
    DependencyProperty.Register( _
        "DataName", GetType(String), GetType(DataNameControl), _
        New PropertyMetadata("KPI", AddressOf OnDataNameChanged))
```

The PropertyChangedCallback should not return a value:

```
Public Shared Sub OnDataNameChanged( _
    ByVal d As DependencyObject, ByVal e As DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs)
    Dim dnc As DataNameControl = CType(d, DataNameControl)
    ...
End Sub
```

Comment: That worked thanks.  I marked it correct, but I don't have enough reputation to share my love!  Somebody with some cred, please upvote!

Answer (score 1):

Newbies (like me),

If you are reading this looking for a solution to your problem, the primary lesson here is, "make sure you are passing the proper parameters to your property registration."  the VS widget will sort of help you through the process but only the first time, after that, if you change the name of your class, VS won't automagically change the class in the registration - that was the source of my problem.

SO a generic example based on the widget code added by VS2013 :

```
Public Shared ReadOnly Prop1Property As DependencyProperty = _
                           DependencyProperty.Register("Prop1", _
                           GetType(String), GetType(Window1), _
                           New PropertyMetadata(Nothing))
```

**Prop1Property** is your property name plus the suffix property.

**"Prop1"** is that property name.

1st **GetType(String)** is the variable type is the type of YOUR property.  VS enters string as a default.

2nd **GetType(Window1)** is simply the class in which your property exists.  VS enters "Window1" as a default.  This is likely never correct and its not linked to anything else in the widget so you will have to change it yourself. I say simply, but this is where I messed up.

**New PropertyMetadata** has 6 overloads depending on how you planning on handling the values of the property.

In this case, **"Nothing"** explicitly states the default value is nothing.
Options include Default values, Property change callbacks, CoerceValueCallback and an IsValidValueCallback.  All of that is a little beyond, my problem.  I have to sort of figure them out to get my code working, so if anybody has questions, reply and I might add some info.

If you are new to Dependency Properties, which the two 10-minute videos.

[Youtube: WPF Tutorial 21 - Dependency Properties](https://youtu.be/XYCHO9K34qA)

They are simple and enough to get you up and running.

Comment: Small correction: The default value **Nothing** doesn't mean that you don't set a default value. It means that you explicitly set **Nothing** as default, in contrast to not specifying PropertyMetadata at all. There is a `DependencyProperty.Register` overload that takes only the first three arguments.